# Navigo at Orly airport

Tags: paris

I am arriving at Orly airport. 
1- Can anyone tell me if i can get the carte decouverte there and charge it for the week ( mon-sun)
. If yes can you please precise where .
Thx in advance.

Comment: I want to buy the Nd and use it on Orly bus. Orlyval isn't covered with ND. I just want to make sure that i can buy it upon my arrival and use it

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a Navigo Découverte pass at any RER station and most Métro stations (those that have a ticket window). At Orly, use the Orlyval shuttle to the Antony train station (RER B line, which also connects with the Métro).